# How to load xib for iPhone 5 display

Tags: ios, tabs, xib

I have an App created with IB with a tab bar and several tabs, one of the tabs views has a background image that cannot automatically be resized (stretched). The view has a dozen buttons hidden behind the background and the location of the buttons must changed as per the background.

I am thinking of copying the XIB file and editing the XIB to select a 568 pixel background image and repositioning the buttons down the page accordingly. Then at runtime I would like to add code to select the 568 pixel when on the iPhone 5 (iPhone x/5 selection is not an issue)".

One last thing, I would like to use the same view controller and connections (if possible), since all code is common. Is it possible to do that? How do I create the XIB and make it visible upon tab selection.

Comment: Use IB to position the buttons with the right autoresize settings, then supply two images `background.png` and `background@2x.png`, the latter will be used for retina (that includes iphone5).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check the height of the screen, and programmatically choose which xib you want to use:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    MyFirstViewController *vc1 = nil;
    MySecondViewController *vc2 = nil;

    if(UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
        CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
        if(screenSize.height == 568) {
            vc1 = [[MyFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LargeFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
            vc2 = [[MySecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LargeSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
        }
        if(screenSize.height == 480) {
            vc1 = [[MyFirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SmallFirstViewController" bundle:nil];
            vc2 = [[MySecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SmallSecondViewController" bundle:nil];
        }
    }
    else if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        // ... Add iPad code here if relevant.
    }

    self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[vc1, vc2];
    self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

To change the tab bar icon image programmatically edit the following in your view controller (replace "YOUR-IMAGE" with the actual name... do not put the extension (such as .png)):

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"YOUR-IMAGE"];
    }
    return self;
}
```

When you create a new xib file, don't forget to select the "File Owner" (under "Placeholders") and set the "Custom Class" to the actual view controller class in the Attributes Inspector.  Also, while the "File Owner" is selected, go to the "Connections Inspector" and drag the "view" outlet to the top level view of your xib.

Comment: I mean my tab bar is created in IB, so I never set the VCs. Based on your answer I am trying to adapt "self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[vc1, vc2];" by copying the property to a mutable array, changing and setting.

Comment: You probably aren't going to be able to easily do what you want if the Tab Bar Controller is in a XIB.  Instead, I'd suggest considering creating the Tab Bar Controller programmatically in a manner like I described above.

Comment: OK, in Application:ApplicationDidFinishLaunching I did the initWithNibName bit and then copied self.tabBarController.viewControllers to a mutable, changed one entry in the mutable and set the self.tabBarController.viewControllers property to my mutable thus changing the one VC. This worked, I got the new background but the image on the tab I changed is now gone. Any ideas? Why?

Comment: JS, I think I will change my code to do as you say as I will fewer tabs for iPad version. Thanks for the help. Cannot upvove yet as do not have 15 credits yet. Btw, the reference manual says the previous VCs are released, how can setting a property release VCs (I am C++ guy). I am not using ARC. Reference: "If you change the value of this property at runtime, the tab bar controller removes all of the old view controllers before installing the new ones". Thanks again.

Comment: @PeterPurple No problem :) As for memory management in Objective-C, objects have a "retain" count which can be "released" by any code that has a valid pointer. Check out my post here: http://www.intertech.com/Blog/Post/Easy-Memory-Management-in-Objective-C-(iPhone-iPad).aspx

Comment: I get that a method can release, but here I am just setting a property; does a property have a body of code? I thought a property was just an attribute as in C++. To be clear, I am referring to "self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[vc1, vc2];"

Comment: Yes, a property is linked to an existing get/set method or it auto-generates one based on the attributes listed with the property.  So `self.tabBarController.viewControllers = @[vc1, vc2];` is actually the same as saying: `[[self tabBarController] setViewControllers:@[vc1, vc2]];`

Comment: ok, I always used synthesize and assumed that's all one could do. Thanks again.

Comment: Regarding the missing tab image and title I mentioned above after setting viewControllers, you can add back, but you cannot do it from the delegate, you ***must*** add it in the VC "initWithNibName" method. "self.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"toolbar-remote.png"];self.title = @"Remote";"

Comment: @PeterPurple Yes, that's what I wrote above: "edit the following in your *view controller*" The reason is that you are never invoking an initWithNibName: method in your delegate, you're sending the message FROM the delegate to the View Controller.